# Creating SSL Local network for downloading an iOS app from local

Tags: ios, html, ssl

I want to create a local SSL network to download an IPA file from it. What should I do?

I have a manifest.plist file and a application.ipa file and I put that on a website recently and it worked fine(download and install on iOS).

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://mywebsite/manifest.plist
```

I want to give a local service to my customers so I should have a `https://mylocaladdress`.

I have a mikrotik router and a lot of problems.

Could I create that local network?
If yes how?

Comment: If you got problems, you should ask more detailled questions. I think no-one here will provide you an out-of-the-box-complete-ssl-server-solution. What server are you currently using? Is the manifest (and the ipa-file thats referenced from there) downloadable via e.g. curl from your local server?

Comment: I wanna use mikrotik router as an accesspoint and create a wireless network that everyone could access .....

Comment: My files will be on router memory and I wanna make this link work:   itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https:// my router ip address/manifest.plist

Comment: If you want to provide more informations, please add them to the question. For someone who might be able to help, it's painful to read all the comments for acquiring informations by bits and pieces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your router can server HTTPS-requests, this should "just work", as long as the router address is fixed.

So you might need a (self-signed?) certificate on the router

Remember that you'd also have to modify the `manifest.plist` file -- this is typically in XML format -- so that it links to the .ipa Installation file (as well as some links to icons) on the router.